# how to get the json respose in two json array

Tags: android, json

i have get the first array of json but the second array come inside the first array in array  ....:
how is solved it

i have get the tweet_image array inside the image array two array how is solve it 
i have get the image path;

```
{
    "feed": [
        {
            "tweet_id": "794",
            "userid": "6",
            "content": "<a href=http://www.punjabkesari.in/news/article-370994>http://www.punjabkesari.in/news/article-370994</a>",
            "favorite_count": "0",
            "reply_count": "0",
            "retweet_count": "0",
            "tweet_location": "",
            "created_date": "2015-06-16 11:49:00",
            "name": "amar bhanu",
            "user_image": "http://sabakuch.com/public/images_upload/avatars/ozone/6_30_imageamar.jpg",
            "tweet_images": {
                "image": [
                    "http://sabakuch.com/public/images_upload/tweet/794_400_1434435540_album143443554069.jpg"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: jsonlint.com tells me that JSON is invalid... I formatted it, please review it.

Comment: Your JSON is 100% valid.
I will give you answer in 2 mins

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
                try {
                    JSONObject _jObject = new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");
                    JSONArray _jArrayFeed  = _jObject.getJSONArray("feed");
                    if (_jArrayFeed.length()>0) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < _jArrayFeed.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject _subObj = _jArrayFeed.getJSONObject(i);
                            String _tweet_id = _subObj.getString("tweet_id");
                            String _userid = _subObj.getString("userid");
                            String _content = _subObj.getString("content");
                            String _favorite_count = _subObj.getString("favorite_count");
                            String _reply_count = _subObj.getString("reply_count");
                            String _retweet_count= _subObj.getString("retweet_count");
                            String _tweet_location = _subObj.getString("tweet_location");
                            String _created_date = _subObj.getString("created_date");
                            String _name = _subObj.getString("name");
                            String _user_image = _subObj.getString("user_image");
                            JSONObject _jObjtweet_images = _subObj.getJSONObject("tweet_images");
                            JSONArray _jArrayImages = _jObjtweet_images.getJSONArray("image");
                            if (_jArrayImages.length()>0) {
                                for (int j = 0; j < _jArrayImages.length(); j++) {
                                    String _image = _jArrayImages.getString(j);
                                }
                            }

                            }

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

And let me know, if you have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
JSONArray array= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("feed");
JSONObject obj= array.getJSONObject(0);    
JSONObject image= obj.getJSONObject("tweet_images");    
JSONArray image_array= image.getJSONArray("image");
String url= image_array.getString(0);
```

[image]

hope it helps :-)